# How to replace a <85> to a new line in bash script

Tags: linux, awk, ascii, special-characters

I’m running out of idea on how to replace this character “**<85>**” to a new line (please treat this as one character only – I think this is a non-printable character).

I tried this one in my script:

```
cat file | awk '{gsub(”<85>”,RS);print}' > /tmp/file.txt
```

but didn’t work.

I hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: If that's the actual code, then you're missing a parenthesis and you're not using the normal double-quote characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tr '\205' '\n' <file > file.txt
```

`tr` is the transliterate command; it translates one character to another (or deletes it, or …).  The version of `tr` on Mac OS X doesn't recognize hexadecimal escapes, so you have to use octal, and octal 205 is hex 85.

I am assuming that the file contains a single byte `'\x85'`, rather than some combination of bytes that is being presented as `<85>`.  `tr` is not good for recognizing multibyte sequences that need to be transliterated.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`: `sed -e $'s/\302\205/\\n/' file > file.txt`

Or `awk`: `awk '{gsub("\302\205","\n")}7'`

The magic here was in converting the `<85>` character to octal codepoints.

I used `hexdump -b` on a file I manually inserted that character into.